# complexity of a randomized search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Consider the following randomized search algorithm on a sorted array `a` of length `n` (in increasing order). `x` can be any element of the array.

```
size_t randomized_search(value_t a[], size_t n, value_t x)
    size_t l = 0;
    size_t r = n - 1;
    while (true) {
        size_t j = rand_between(l, r);
        if (a[j] == x) return j;
        if (a[j] < x) l = j + 1;
        if (a[j] > x) r = j - 1;
    }
}
```

What is the expectation value of the [Big Theta complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) (bounded both below and above) of this function when `x` is selected randomly from `a`?

Although this seems to be `log(n)`, I carried out an experiment with instruction count, and found out that the result grows a little faster than `log(n)` (according to my data, even `(log(n))^1.1` better fit the result).

Someone told me that this algorithm has an **exact** big theta complexity (so obviously `log(n)^1.1` is not the answer). So, could you please give the time complexity along with your approach to prove it? Thanks.

---

Update: the data from my experiment

`log(n)` fit result by mathematica:

[image: log(n)]

`log(n)^1.1` fit result:

[image: log(n)^1.1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to switch to counting three-way compares, I can tell you the exact complexity.

Suppose that the key is at position i, and I want to know the expected number of compares with position j. I claim that position j is examined if and only if it's the first position between i and j inclusive to be examined. Since the pivot element is selected uniformly at random each time, this happens with probability 1/(|i - j| + 1).

The total complexity is the expectation over i <- {1, ..., n} of sum_{j=1}^n 1/(|i - j| + 1), which is

```
  sum_{i=1}^n 1/n sum_{j=1}^n 1/(|i - j| + 1)
= 1/n sum_{i=1}^n (sum_{j=1}^i 1/(i - j + 1) + sum_{j=i+1}^n 1/(j - i + 1))
= 1/n sum_{i=1}^n (H(i) + H(n + 1 - i) - 1)
= 1/n sum_{i=1}^n H(i) + 1/n sum_{i=1}^n H(n + 1 - i) - 1
= 1/n sum_{i=1}^n H(i) + 1/n sum_{k=1}^n H(k) - 1  (k = n + 1 - i)
= 2 H(n + 1) - 3 + 2 H(n + 1)/n - 2/n
= 2 H(n + 1) - 3 + O(log n / n)
= 2 log n + O(1)
= Theta(log n).
```

(log means natural log here.) Note the -3 in the low order terms. This makes it look like the number of compares is growing faster than logarithmic at the beginning, but the asymptotic behavior dictates that it levels off. Try excluding small n and refitting your curves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please give me several minutes to understand it. For the curve thing, I intentionally started at 1000, hoping that constants won't affect much.

Comment: @KevinSayHi Start even higher? From experience, it's really quite difficult to distinguish between x and x^1.1 empirically. You might find plotting the average running time over log n and observing the limit more edifying.

Comment: Your reasoning is very convincing, but sorry I kinda got stuck at line 3 of computation. We have `2/n sum_{i=1}^n H(i) - 1`, but how do we jump to the fourth line? I'm not quite proficient at discrete math, sorry.

Comment: @KevinSayHi I added a couple of steps. The harmonic numbers have a closed-form sum that I never remember off the top of my head. Type `Sum[HarmonicNumber[i],{i,1,n}]` into Mathematica.

Comment: I have two questions. What do you mean by three-way compare ? and why do we have 1/n in the solution of the complexity at the first line ?

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai Three-way compare => two elements go in, either "less than", "equal to", or "greater than" comes out. The 1/n factor is because we're taking an expectation over n equiprobable outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `rand_between` to implement sampling from a uniform probability distribution in constant time, the expected running time of this algorithm is Θ(lg *n*). Informal sketch of a proof: the expected value of `rand_between(l, r)` is `(l+r)/2`, the midpoint between them. So each iteration is expected to skip half of the array (assuming the size is a power of two), just like a single iteration of binary search would.

More formally, borrowing from an analysis of [quickselect](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m19w03/public_html/Section6-6.pdf), observe that when you pick a random midpoint, half of the time it will be between ¼*n* and ¾*n*. Neither the left nor the right subarray has more than ¾*n* elements. The other half of the time, neither has more than *n* elements (obviously). That leads to a recurrence relation

```
T(n) = ½T(¾n) + ½T(n) + f(n)
```

where f(*n*) is the amount of work in each iteration. Subtracting ½T(n) from both sides, then doubling both sides, we have

```
½T(n) = ½T(¾n) + f(n)
T(n) = T(¾n) + 2f(n)
```

Now, since 2f(*n*) = Θ(1) = Θ(*n* ᶜ log⁰ *n*) where *c* = log(1) = 0, it follows by the master theorem that T(n) = Θ(*n*⁰ lg *n*) = Θ(lg *n*).

Comment: You are making the assumption that expectation of `rand_between` can be passed to the expectation of the whole algorithm, which is too naive before you can prove it to convince me.

Comment: Also, I've posted the result of my experiment above. The curve grows a little bit faster than `log(n)`.

Comment: @KevinSayHi: posted a proof.